# Vue.js conditional if else

Tags: html, vue.js

need some help, thanks.

I don't know how to write the proper condition in vue for my task.

i got those 2 values

content.Image &
header.Background

Basically what i want to do is to check if there is a jpeg to content.Image assigned as background-image then use this image as background, else use the jpeg that is assigned in header.Background.

```
:style="{'background-image': ($_.isEmpty(content.Image) ? '' : 
'url('+_CONFIG.media_url + content.Image +')') }">
```

thats as far as i could get i want some kind of if-else condition but i dont have any clue how to properly write the code for it.

Comment: I think you should use a computed property called `imageTest` to test background image and return `true` if it is set to `$_.isEmpty(content.image)`. Then, in your style binding, test `this.imageTest == true ? ...`

Answer (score 0):

try using computed property to provide boolean:

```
...
:style="[this.imageTest == true ? {} : 
{'url('+_CONFIG.media_url + content.Image +')') }]"
...

...
computed: {
   imageTest () {
      if (document.getElementById('idOfBackgroundImage') === $_.isEmpty(content.Image)) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
...
```